# WPF MVVM fulscreen application resolution fit

Tags: wpf, mvvm, fullscreen, resolution

I'm making a game in WPF MVVM. I'm doing it in fullscreen and im trying to position every control(I have property for width, height and margin) for every control. It's little problematic.

Is there any way to make controls, pages to automatically fit to screen resolution?

At now im making following thing:
in view model im calculating coefficient( screen width / design width ) and then I multiply every width by this coefficient. I do the same with height.

Is it possible to position it in xaml and make it fit for every screen resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will automatically scale its children.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things the hard way.  Use something like a `Grid` to setup your layout.

Look at this example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Hello, World" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Height="95"/>
    <Button Content="Fixed Size" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="95"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Expanded Size 1" 
            Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="Expanded Size 2" 
            Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

This is what happens:

1. Your Row 0 will auto size to whatever you either 1. specify as the height of the control or 2. if you don't specify the height, it will auto size to how much room is needed for the content to be visible
2. Your Row 1 is a fixed size, so even though the `Button`s height is set, that row will only be 50 pixels!  Since the `VerticalAlignment` is set, you would see, top-right corner as your reference, the "0th" y-pixel to the "49th"  (down) y-pixel
3. See #4
4. Since the Grid has two RowDefinition set with a Height = *, this means they will take up the maximum amount of space they can that is remaining after the other controls are drawn.  Think of it as addition. `* + * = 2*`. That means each row will take up half of the remaining space in the Y direction.  You had:

   ```
   ...
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
   ```

   instead, that means (remember, * + 3* = 4*) the Row with Height * will take up 1/4 of the remaining space and Row with Height 3* will take up 3/4 of the remaining space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it could be good for static windows like main menu, but on game window with about ~30 elements and some of them need to change position during game will give me horrible matrix. Also I think management this moves at this matrix will be problematic.

Comment: I guess, I was just answering the question on how to make controls fit full screen resolution.  I think your best bet it to write a custom grid control that handles all your sizing.

Comment: also, don't forget RowSpan and ColumnSpan.